# menu always repositioning

Tags: html, css

I was trying to make a menubar and a login page with using a `div`, but when I resize my browser (I am using Chrome) the `div` changes and goes to the sides.

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/xVenw/

As you can see, it is not a line of menu. It adds another line when it is resized.

Comment: What link?  I see a 'k' that has no seemingly significant value.

Comment: the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/xVenw/

Comment: I put k cause it told me to put code which I already putted in jfiddle

Comment: Add the code to the question?  Questions are supposed to be self-contained.  That's why the warning is there.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the menu items to wrap, use `white-space: nowrap` and make the list items `display: inline-block`:

```
nav > ul > li {
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

I would recommend cleaning up your code, it's quite messy in the Fiddle, and there are many repeat and vague CSS selectors.